# Where can I download newest OS images for my Bq Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Where can I download newest OS images for my Bq Ubuntu Phone? Or is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ where it says "Upgrading manually"